# Получить середину массива — System.IndexOutOfRangeException?

Tags: c#

```
SliderArray[SliderArray.Length / 2] = sldr0.Value;
```

> System.IndexOutOfRangeException: "Индекс находился вне границ массива."

Пробовал и

```
SliderArray[SliderArray.Length-1 / 2] = sldr0.Value;
```

```
SliderArray = new double[VideoArray.Length];//по длине такой же как и VideoArray
VideoArray = new CompositionTarget[MyMedia.Source.UserInfo.Length];
```

Comment: А чему равно `SliderArray.Length`? И какого оно в точности типа?

Comment: Да, у вас случайно нету многопоточного доступа в коде? В общем, давайте нам [mcve].

Comment: `SliderArray` - пустой

Comment: @BadCats: Отлично, а `MyMedia.Source.UserInfo.Length` чему равно?

Comment: число, число там какое?

Comment: ну это свойство - я не смотрел его значение

Comment: @BadCats: А мы должны сами угадать, какое оно именно? Ну так посмотрите. Информация о том, что «длина массива `SliderArray` такая же, как и массив `VideoArray`», не помогает ни капли.

Comment: и не смотрите. На фига, когда есть StackOverflow?

Comment: да, ноль - вывел в label

Comment: извините что так долго

Comment: @BadCats ну, собственно, все прояснилось

Comment: @BadCats: Ну отлично, тогда ответ на вопрос вам понятен и без нас.